# I would like my id to shake when the user clicks a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i would like my id to shake when a user clicks it, how can i achieve that? I am a beginner in jquery and am currently finishing up php, I am going to study jquery next.example:https://twitter.com/signup

this is my html:

```
<input id="sub" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
```

and this is my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
               $( document ).click(function() {
      $( "#sub" ).effect( "shake",{distance:100} );
    });
     </script>
```

also if i wanted to implement times and direction would i do this?:

```
    $( "#sub" ).effect( "shake",{direction:right},{distance:100},{times:6} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/kx8q8/2/

Use `#sub` instead of `document` on click.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#sub").click(function () {
        $(this).effect("shake", {
            direction: 'right'
        }, {
            distance: 100
        }, {
            times: 6
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried your code but it still is not working, the jsfiddle you posted is the correct effect i want when clicked. By the way am using a chrome browser if that helps

Comment: tried it and nothing, no shake when i click submit. Is there a extra code I should write?

Comment: @johnlondon GO to join.me site and click on 'start meeting' once the meeting is started, share the 9 digit code with me.

Comment: i have the code but i didn't want to post it public is there a send message function on here?

Comment: @johnlondon Send me on my email address.

Comment: i tried looking on your profile for your email but i dont see it

Comment: @johnlondon aditya.adiioo77@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

**JSBIN**: http://jsbin.com/uGAMulOL/3/

Add the # for the sub id element and put `right` in quotes. Also the options should be fixed in the object literal.

```
$("#sub").click(function() {
    $(this).effect("shake",{direction:'right',distance:100,times:6000});
});
```